# Closing tabs in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am wondering how I can close tabs on my browser without getting all the prompts asking if i want to. I just want to hit the close button and have it close. I have tried finding any options and such but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: There is an add-on that does this. I would use that.

Answer (score 1):

If you open several tabs, it is normal the browser alerts you that you are going to leave several websites and not only one. I rather find that functionality important and useful. It is the default behavior  I personally advise you to use it.

The browser does not offer options through its GUI to achieve what you are looking for. In the past, an extra feature called [Chrome ToolBox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-toolbox-by-google/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn) extension is used for that; however it is not longer supported by Chrome:

> We no longer provide this extension because most features were made in
>   NPAPI and NPAPI is no longer supported in Chrome.

There are some [alternative extensions](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-extensions-chrome-tab-management/) but no one of them (AFAIK) will allow you to close all the tabs in one single click.

Answer (score 0):

url         chrome://settings/

On Startup: Continue where you left off

This will eliminate this issue, but the tabs will be there when you start a new Chrome session. The reason you are alerted is because the default action is to close all tabs when closing Chrome (essentially you are requesting "kill all tabs") and they won't be there when you come back -- hence the alert.

If you are experiencing this with only some web sites, it's the "java script" that's programmed into that particular website to try and keep you there. You can install a "java script" toggle add-on to disable javascripts temporarily.

However, if you are still only referring to closing a single tab, then you shouldn't be alerted to close a single tab, then it's the site and it's script. Right click at tab, choose close. Click the x on the tab to close it. Ctrl + W will also close a tab.